# Dataframe select rows where certain columns are sup to value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I'm trying to filter a data-frame and leave only the rows where a list of columns are superior to 50M

```py
  Name      USD  GPB        DNR
0 jsk        0    0         154156151
1 psg        0    5444      0
2 om         0    51541477  0
3 barca      0    0         0
4 real       0    93636     55115
```

what I'm able to do but it's only filtring with one column

```py
df_sup50M = df_sup50M[df_sup50M.USD >= 5000000]
```

expected output:

```
  Name      USD  GPB        DNR
0 jsk        0    0         154156151
1 om         0    51541477  0
```

Comment: You told it to only subset on one column. If you want to subset on more than one column, do that.

Comment: @ifly6 because when I try :
``df_sup50M = df_sup50M[df_sup50M.USD >= 5000000 or df_sup50M.GPB >= 5000000]`` I get an error

Comment: Syntaxes are `df[(df.col > blah) | (df.col1 > blah) | (df.col3 > blah)]`, intermediate dfs which execute each subset command in turn, or chained `df.query(condition)` statements

Answer (score 1):

```
#Mutiple or conditions
df = df[(df['USD'] >= 5000000) | (df['GPB'] >= 5000000) | (df['DNR'] >= 5000000)]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: how can I do that if the columns are variable
I just know that the first column is a name and others should be compared